# VisualStudio Code Javascript IntelliSense breaks on export or import

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following two files and a `jsconfig.json` file in a directory.

```
/** myclass.js **/
class MyClass {
     constructor() {}
     
     myMethod() {}
}
```

```
/** test.js **/

/** @type {MyClass} */
let test;
```

The `jsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6"
    },
}
```

If I use the above code as is, I get method suggestion in the `test.js` file. However, as soon as I try to export out the `MyClass` class definition from `myclass.js` (by adding for example `export default MyClass;` on the end of that file) auto suggestion stops working, and IntelliSense does not recognize the `MyClass` class anymore.

I presume that this is a `jsconfig.json` issue, but I can't figure out why is this happening.

I am using **Visual Studio Code v1.46.1** and I have the **ESLint v2.1.5** extension installed on it.